# Madison has a choice of two entrees (soup or salad), three main courses (fish, chicken or steak) and three desserts (ice-cream, lemon tart or cheese).

Tags: probability

Madison has a choice of two entrees (soup or salad), three main courses (fish, chicken or steak) and three desserts (ice-cream, lemon tart or cheese).

c. Suppose that Madison has the choice to omit the entree and/or the dessert course altogether. Find the probability that:

i. she chooses only two courses.

I have no idea how to work this, I've been trying to 'count' on a tree diagram for hours and I don't know how they get an answer of 15/36.

I know that there are 36 choices because are extra "none" options for the entree and dessert so 3 x 3 x 4.

Answer (score 2):

She could omit either the entree or the dessert, so that would be an entree and main, or a main and a dessert, or main only or, she can have all three (as these omissions are just options).

So there will be a total of $36$ possible combinations:
$2*3*3$ - all three courses ; $3$ - for the main only ; $3*2$ - main and an entree ; 3x3 - main and a dessert.

She has $3 * 2 + 3 * 3 = 15$ options for two courses. Therefore, $P(2$ courses$)$ $=$ $\frac{15}{36} .$

You can also draw a tree diagram with the starting choice being the three mains then the next branches would be entree, desert or none. Then you could find the various probabilities.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The two courses are either entree and main, or main and dessert.  The first has six options, the second has nine.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand it. So there a 6 options for entree and main which are soup, salad, none and fish, chicken and steak. And then the options for main and dessert are fish, chicken, steak and ice cream, lemon tart, cheese and none? Where do you get the 9 from? Could you also use a tree diagram if possible

Comment: You can't have none because then you would have only one course.